# Onload url contents on to a div using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have the following `div` structure:

```html
<div class = "maindiv" data-bind="foreach: $data[1]">   <a >
     <span id="Name" data-bind="text:$data.Url"></span>    </a> </div>
```

On load of the page is it possible to show the contents of url in the "`maindiv`"?

Onclick of `span` I am aware I could use jQuery's `$().html("url")` to load contents, but is it possible to do so on load of a page?

Answer (score 3):

You should do two things:

1. Create an observable that contains the *data* from that URL.
2. Bind that observable with `html` binding.

Here's an example:

```js
// Mock out jQuery ajax calls
var $ = {
  ajax: function(opts) {
    // ignore URL and so forth in this mock, just call success
    // simulate latency with setTimeout
    setTimeout(function() {
      opts.success("<strong>Your</strong> fancy <em>html</em> result from url: <code>" + opts.url + "</code>.");
    }, Math.random() * 1000 + 1000);
  }
}

function Item(i) {
  var self = this;
  self.url = "http://example.com/"+i+".html";
  self.urlContents = ko.observable("not loaded yet");
  $.ajax({
    url: self.url,
    success: function(html) { self.urlContents(html); }
  });
}

function ViewModel() {
  this.items = ko.observableArray([new Item("A123"), new Item("XYZ456789")]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
.maindiv { padding: 10px; border: 1px solid blue; }
span { padding: 10px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="maindiv" data-bind="foreach: items">   
  <a>
     <span data-bind="html: urlContents"></span>
  </a> 
</div>
```

PS. Do not use `id` attributes inside a `foreach`: they must be unique inside your html document and will not be unique if there are multiple items in the list you're foreaching over.